Objectionable objects during different months
Bhagavata purana says objectionable objects should be avoided during the months.

Those (objectionable) objects (e.g. vegetables in the month of Śrāvaṇa, curds in the month of Bhādrapada) should be given up during the course of those specific months.

What are these objects for different months of the year?
Translator in the above link provides couple of examples but I am looking for all 12 months, and potentially Adhika masa, if there is specifics.

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-bhagavata-purana/d/doc1113133.html
